# HTML & CSS: Split page horizontally with vertical scrollbars

Tags: html, css

I can't find how to do something that should be very simple. I want to divide page to two panes horizontally. Between the panes there's some border (wheter it can be resized or not I don't care). The upper pane can scroll vertically, while the lower pane stay fixed.

I tried bootstrap sticky fixed footer, but I don't have scroller for top part there.

My eventual goal is to insert all kind of links in bottom fixed pane that will help navigating to places in the top pane.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @zzzzBov i've enjoyed reading the article that you share, thank you.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I tried Bootstrap - it's in the body of the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an option where your elements will take whole screen. If you want to limit their size to bootstrap container you need to put them in container and give it style of `position:relative`

```
<div class="upper">This will scroll</div>
<div class="lower">This will not</div>


.upper, .lower {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.upper {
  top: 0;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: pink;  
  overflow:scroll;
}

.lower {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: blue;    
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jGBh3/

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I have no idea why this question was so downvoted and on hold, but I'm happy to found an answer.

Comment: Yeah, Sometimes people are upset if the question looks like you haven't try enough:). They haven't seen any code examples etc. Next time, add sample code :)